# C# Lambda | Difference between Method(Callback) and Method(() => Callback())

Tags: c#, lambda

My question concerns the execution difference between

```
void Method1(Action callback)
{
    Method2(callback);
}
```

and

```
void Method3(Action callback)
{
    Method4(() => callback());
}
```

When using the first approach, will the callback Action be called at that moment. Or is there, execution wise, no difference between the two approaches?

Are there any real differences between the two approaches at all?

Comment: The second approach declares a new Action within which you call the callback. The same way you should use less temporary or unneeded variables as possible, you shouldn't make useless indirect calls.

Answer (score 2):

There are two small differences:

1. If an error happens in the callback, the stacktrace will include the lambda in the second example.
2. When you use reflection, the [`Target`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.target(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.method(v=vs.110).aspx) fields of the [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) instance will differ.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any real differences between the two approaches at all?

The latter one puts an extra (anonymous) method on the callstack, but other than that there is really very little if any difference

The major difference is the second approach allows you to pass arguments in the case that `Method3` and `Method4` do not share the same signature of `Action`

```
void Method3(Action<string,string> callback)
{
    Method4(() => callback(arg1,arg2));
}
```

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy its called "Showing the difference by way of example". Please just downvote or move on or whatever.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy You make that assumption to show why you might want to pass the lambda to Method4.  Ie, if method4 expects an Action, using the lambda allows Method3 to select the arguments on the callback and pass an argument free lambda to method4.

Comment: Although I think the answer would be clearer if you emphasised that you changed the signature of Method3.

Answer (score 0):

I would say a big one. In the first one you are just passing a delegate to a different function, where in the second one you are creating a new delegate with a closure variable that holds the first delegate that will be executed once the first one is. Believe it or no you created something called `<>c_DisplayClass1` a subclass inside your original class(For more info check [this](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/12/internals-of-delegate.html)). A simple way to see what is going on here is to look at the expression tree in debug mode of something like this

```
Action a = () => Console.WriteLine("A");
Expression<Action> exp = () => a();
```

And since `Action` is just a 'delegate void Action()' and a delegate is a type that inherits from [Delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/dotnet/api/system.delegate?view=netframework-4.7) it will work the same.